# Change state of button depending on the text above in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

How can I write a method in cypress so that I search for the text content "Clinic location is active?" and after finding this text operate the button below it (you have a printscreen for guidance [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S0g3.jpg) ).

Until now I had written this method to operate the button to be active / inactive after the redClass class, but to be detected by its position on the page, which is slightly useless if a button appears in front of it in the future:

```
setToOn(value: number) {
        cy.get(this.controlsSelector).eq(value).then(($button) => {
            if ($button.hasClass('redClass')) {
                cy.get(this.offSliderButton).eq(value).click({force:true});
            } 
          })
    }
```

Now I would like not to look for the button by its position (value in the case of the above method), called with the function cypress .eq(), but by the text that is above it, in the control-label class

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Clinic location is active?</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="checkboxControl no-select">
                <div class="checkboxSlider  change greenClass">
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-on">Yes</div>
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-off">No</div>
                    <input checked="checked" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Clinic location is active? field is required." id="IsActive" name="IsActive" placeholder="Clinic location is active?" type="checkbox" value="true">
                    <input name="IsActive" type="hidden" value="true">
                    <label class="grey"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I want to call a method,from the test file, like:

`clinicLocations.operateButtons('Clinic location is active?').setToOn();`

Code for another button from that page:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Allow Online Scheduling?</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="checkboxControl no-select">
                <div class="checkboxSlider  change greenClass">
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-on">Yes</div>
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-off">No</div>
                    <input checked="checked" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Allow Online Scheduling? field is required." id="AllowOnlineScheduling" name="AllowOnlineScheduling" placeholder="Allow Online Scheduling?" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="AllowOnlineScheduling" type="hidden" value="true">
                    <label class="grey"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And another code structure for an inactive button (with redClass) :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Use service facility NPI number in box 32a of HCFA form?</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div data-toggle-selector=".NPInumberBox32a" class="checkboxControl no-select">
                <div class="checkboxSlider redClass">
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-on">Yes</div>
                    <div class="checkboxSlider-state checkboxSlider-state-off">No</div>
                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Use service facility NPI number in box 32a of HCFA form? field is required." id="UseFacilityNPINoInHCFA" name="UseFacilityNPINoInHCFA" placeholder="Use service facility NPI number in box 32a of HCFA form?" type="checkbox" value="false"><input name="UseFacilityNPINoInHCFA" type="hidden" value="false">
                    <label class="grey"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I have provided all the necessary information.

Comment: Can you provide a full HTML that includes other buttons? I can write an answer but it may not work without knowing the structure of all of the buttons

Comment: I posted a code for another button slider on the page and another one for an inactive tutton , as an idea, i hope that will help you

Comment: Hmm, do not all buttons have a label on the page?

Comment: I hope to not get wrong, but all buttons have "<label class="grey"></label>"

Comment: You're right, my bad. I have now modified the code of the other buttons and they all have the code with <label class = "control-label" ...

Answer (score 2):

In terms of Cypress commands it's just this

```js
cy.contains('.form-group', 'Clinic location is active')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .click()
```

I don't understand what `clinicLocations.operateButtons` refers to, or what your `setOn()` is doing exactly, but above is correct Cypress code for your requirement.

Comment: The tests I do are done with page object and separate classes. Sequence with "clinicLocations." it means I'm calling from the cypress test, a class that's in another file. Regarding "setOn ()", I want to check when I call this if the button is off or on. If it's off, move it on, and if it's on, don't do anything, but check that it is. For this, logic is already thought out in the code above, and if I could call directly that method it would be ideal. That's why I want to call "setOn ()" or "setOff ()" after finding the button on the page

Comment: And by the way, even if i use your code, i have this error: "Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<input checked="checked" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Clinic location is active? field is required." id="IsActive" name="IsActive" placeholder="Clinic location is active?" type="checkbox" value="true">

This element <input#IsActive.form-control> is not visible because it has CSS property: visibility: hidden

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking"  I tried with {force:true}, in vain

Comment: It works with the HTML you gave above, what else did you miss out? Of course, you can do what the message says and add {force:true} to the click().

Comment: The main problem is probably that it scrolls down before clicking on that item, and after clicking even with {force: true}, it doesn't work. Can you still show me how I can call using a method that has code written by you, a setToOn() method, for example?